# Delete first item in dictionary in Python with Apahce-beam

Tags: python, apache-beam

I'm trying delete the first item in of this list

[13,-36,1633625404,30,3,31,15,36,57,24.6]

With Apache-beam pipeline in Python

I create some methods that transform the list to

['13', '-36', '1633625404', '30', '3', '31', '15', '36', '57', '24.6']

otherwise don't work anyway, but when I try create a method,

```
def delete_first(list):
    return elemento.pop(0)
```

return to my console only "13"

What can I do to return

['-36', '1633625404', '30', '3', '31', '15', '36', '57', '24.6']

Answer (score 1):

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

lst = lst[1:]

print(lst)

> [2, 3, 4]

Comment: but I need create a method or pipeline code that can run to all my data, not to only 1 line